# Resume Template: Undefined Control Sequence, \write18 Errors

Tags: xetex, texshop, cv

Here is the [source code](http://pastebin.com/6cbgVqnX).

This is the full text I receive on the console:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)
(preloaded format=xetex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./untitled.tex
./untitled.tex:12: Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \documentclass
                   [10pt, letterpaper]{article}
?
```

Notes:

- I am running it on TeXShop
- Compiling requires XeTeX
- It uses commercial fonts
- The source code is from Jason Blevins
- Here is a [page](http://jblevins.org/projects/cv-template/) to
  the source code along with descriptions of the packages, etc

Questions:

1. Why I am I receiving this error? I have tried formatting it
   differently but to no avail.
2. I have updated my TeX Live Utility to the current version, do I need to install other packages or some other thing?
3. What can I do to make it compile, precisely to make it look like the above mentioned CV?

Comment: Welcome! You need to run `xelatex` - not `xetex`.

Comment: @cfr: Thank you for the welcome and the answer. I just ran it, and received an error for what it seems to be the font. Here is the [image](http://imgur.com/a/jVVTN) of the console after I run `xelatex`. If the font is the problem, would you happen to know if I have to install it and how would I install it with little to no hassle? Thank you once again.

Comment: I just became aware that Garamond Premier Pro is a font I must purchase, thus I ought to use free fonts from Google. I was then wondering sort of again, how I would install a font for use on my LaTeX files? I assume it would be through TeX Live Utility but I may be mistaken.

Comment: What does that have to do with the question? You are using XeTeX: just install it for your system. On OS X, use Font Book or whatever.

Comment: My apologies. Okay, so let's say I have Hoefler Text on my Font Book. How would I include the font Hoefler Text Regular in the .tex file (source code I included in the question)? I tried `\setmainfont{Hoefler Text Regular}` but that did not work.

Comment: But that's how it works. You have it installed on your system and then just use its name with `\setmainfont`. Take care that you do not add or remove any name part (e.g. "Regular"). Be also sure you replace `Chaparral Pro Subhead` with an appropriate font if you do not have that installed.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to replace the font definitions to use those fonts which are installed on your system. Hoefler Text should work on most versions of macOS/OSX.

```
% Body
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}

% Title
\newfontfamily\titleface{Hoefler Text}
\newcommand{\titlefont}[1]{{\titleface\large\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

% Section Headings
\newfontfamily\sectionface{Hoefler Text}
\sectionfont{\sectionface\mdseries\normalsize\uppercase}
\subsectionfont{\sectionface\mdseries\normalsize\itshape}
```

Make sure that TeXShop uses `XeLaTex` as the compiler and you are good to go. Read the [fontspec manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontspec), if want to make further adjustments to font selection.

Comment: That is not going to work with `article` which is the class used in the question. Also, `XeLaTex` is only likely to work on a case-insensitive system. (I don't know where OS X is with this - it used to be a strange mixture of case-insensitive and case-sensitive.) And will this really work on most versions of Mac OS, as well as most versions of Mac OS X?

Comment: @cfr Using the template liked in the question und making my proposed adjustments, I was able to produce a PDF (I am running 10.11.6). I am not sure, if I get your question right: I was referring to only to OSX and macOS (the "new" OSX, as it is now called, starting with Sierra 10.12).